# How to add library search path on Alpine Linux? ldconfig

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, ldconfig

I'm trying to build a dockerfile for installing [saprfc](http://sap.github.io/node-rfc/install.html#sap-nw-rfc-library-installation) on an Alpine linux base image.

The instructions say to create `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nwrfcsdk.conf` and to put `/usr/local/sap/nwrfcsdk/lib` in the `nwrfcsdk.conf` file. ldconfig should then load the saprfc libraries.

However, I have learned that ldconfig on Alpine does not read from `ld.so.conf.d`. `ldconfig -p` is also not a recognized option.

So how do you add a custom library search path on Alpine Linux?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. My java needed additional library paths for setcap to work:

```
echo "/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/amd64/jli:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server" > /etc/ld-musl-x86_64.path
```

From [musl manual](https://www.musl-libc.org/doc/1.0.0/manual.html):

```
../etc/ld-musl-$(ARCH).path, taken relative to the location of
the "program interpreter" specified in the program's headers -
 if present, this will be processed as a text file containing 
the shared library search path, with components delimited by 
newlines or colons. If absent, a default path of 
"/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib" will be used. 
Not used by static-linked programs.
```

The exact path used by ld might be different for your arch, I found out mine by doing:

```
# strace java ... 2>&1 | grep ld
open("/etc/ld-musl-x86_64.path", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```